# Grid Cell editing plugin

Tags: javascript, extwebcomponents

I am trying to use grid cell editing plugin for tree grid. I can see event complete  but dont know how to use it fetch other columns of the record. Or can save changes into database?

[Event Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJeZN.png)

Regards
Nidhi

Comment: You can use **contenteditable="true"** attribute inside cell and get value on blur event and also pass other attribute for save in database.

Comment: @RaeeshAlam It didnot work with extwebcomponets. Where should I provide the event code on grid listtener or column itself?  {complete: function(sender, value, startValue,eOpts){alert('complete'); console.log(eOpts);console.log(value);}} Here I am getting value but I need to fetch value of other column of this record but I dont get how to find. I need other column to map with database primary key so that I can store changed value against it.

Comment: You can find **.parent()** method to other columns value & you can provide example on https://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: @RaeeshAlam here is example https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/39v5. I want text column value on edit duration